# Is address of global variables the same for different runs of the program?

Tags: c++, virtual-memory

Consider the following code snippet

```
int i=10;
int main()
{
    cout<<&i;
}
```

Once an exe is generated for the program, will the output be the same for different runs of the program? Assume that the OS supports virtual memory

Edit:The ques is specific to global variables which are stored in data segment. Since this is the first global variable, should the address come out to be same or different?

Comment: @AndreasBjørn 'random' in RAM doesn't exactly mean that..

Comment: I think &i will return the virtual address of the variable, hence it should not be related to the random access of the physical memory.

Comment: Why do you want to rely on this?

Comment: It depends on your OS, and other factors. There is no single answer.

Comment: @AndreasBjørn For the purpose of this question, can we agree that the only person talking about physical memory is you, and that the question is about virtual addressing.

Comment: If it matters to you, you're doing something wrong. Why exactly do you care? Idle curiosity is a perfectly valid reason, but you should never write code that depends on the address being the same *or* on it being different.

Comment: @KeithThompson I am doing it just for understanding some concepts, not actually coding it.

Comment: @AndreasBjørn: Just to be clear, the "random" in "random access memory" doesn't mean that *at all*. "Random access" means that accesses to different addresses have the same cost. This is in contrast to storage devices like disks and tapes, where the time it takes to access a given location can depend on where it is. Some systems may randomize addresses, but only if they do so deliberately (for security reasons).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You always get the same addresses if [ASLR](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Address_space_layout_randomization) is disabled. You get unpredictable addresses if ASLR is enabled.

Answer (score 3):

The *virtual* address will be whatever the linker decided. The *physical* address will vary with each load.

Comment: On Windows, the virtual address will be whatever the linker decided, so long as the module can load at the preferred address. On systems that use PIC code, then the virtual address will be whatever the loader decides.

Answer (score 1):

Simple answer: It depends :-)

If your OS starts for a program always the same environment with a virtual memory range which looks always the same, the output should be always the same.

But if you run the same os on different hardware ( maybe with different amount of ram available ) it could be res ult in a different address but normally the address is also the same, independent of the hardware.

But you should NEVER expect that the result is the same! In a short: Don't think about the virtual or real address of data in your prog. This is under control from the compiler, the OS and maybe some libraries as well. So simply ignore it!

Answer (score 1):

Short answer: **on a user-mode program running on a x86-64 machine: no, you shouldn't assume that for any reason ever**.

---

Long answer: It might happen that the address is the same but that is absolutely not guaranteed (at least on a program running on a x86_64 OS and machine).

I read some confusion about virtual/physical memory and how come that an address is "*random*" so let me explain something at a high-level view:

Targeting a x86_64 architecture and OS (let's say Windows) you can't even assume that the operating system itself will load all its components into memory in the same physical locations (some exceptions for the old bootloader conventions at [0000:7C00H](http://www.tavi.co.uk/os2pages/boot.html), I have no idea how that works in a UEFI environment).

After segmentation (used or not depends on the OS, usually Windows just sets some plain segments for usermode and kernelmode) is put in place, once you switch to protected mode (or long) you again have no control on how the OS manages the virtual memory mechanism which hides layers of complexity and MMU-related operations to give your process an address space of its own.

Plus there are security measures in place: the linker might decide the [base address](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms680339(v=vs.85).aspx) for your executable but in other cases when [ASLR](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Address_space_layout_randomization) is activated the OS can move its modules and your executable around as it pleases for security purposes.

Conclusion: unless you're dealing with very low-level stuff (e.g. physical addresses or directly writing memory areas on an external device) you should absolutely not rely on the address of the variable being the same across different runs. There's **no guarantee** on that.