# C++) What determines Global variable address? Why It is fixed?

Tags: c++, variables, memory-address

Whenever I compile, the memory address of the global variable is fixed.

However, if I turn VS off and turn it on again, the address is changed.

I want to know why.

Why is the global variable address not related to the module address, and does the address change if I re-run the compiler? What determines the global variable address?

Comment: Because that's how your operating system works. Which is completely irrelevant, as far as C++ is concerned. C++ is so awesome, that you can write code with hundreds of thousands of lines, and not care to the least as to where in memory each individual object exists, why, and how.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is address of global variables the same for different runs of the program?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24952585/is-address-of-global-variables-the-same-for-different-runs-of-the-program) (If not, no worries. That question asks "is" and you asked "why". There is some overlap, hence maybe the answers to the other question will satisfy your curiosity.)